# os.kill not working as expected with Spyder on Windows

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

My Python (3.6) script starts a subprocess that handles SIGINT (CTRL_C_EVENT) and SIGTERM.
Everything works fine with Terminal or Powershell.
However, when run in Spyder (3.2.4)/Ipython, I get an error for os.kill(..):

`SystemError: <built-in function kill> returned a result with an error set`

with traceback:

`OSError: [WinError 6] The Handle is invalid.`

When starting another scirpt with Popen that sends the CTRL_C_EVENT with os.kill, the first subprocess gets stoped but not as I want it to. Both, CTRL_C_EVENT and SIGTERM seem to become a SIGKILL instead and the process ends unclean.

I can start it with
Configuration Per File > Execute In An External System Terminal
but that is not really a good solution in this case (would confuse other users etc etc).

Updating IPython didn´t help.

Using creationflags for Popen doens´t seem to help.
Starting other suprocesses and trying to stop them cleanly brings the same result.

Does somebody know why this happens and why Ipython handles it differently?
Any way to get it run in the IPython console?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
I thought I would keep it short and leave code away as it doesn´t seem that important for this problem, but here some more info.
I have tried it with different solutions and subprocesses with the same result. One for example I start with:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False, start_new_session=True)
```

Which simply starts an .exe that handles the Signals mentioned above.

When calling

```
os.kill(proc.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
```

everything works fine when run in Terminal or Powershell. I does not however in Spyders IPython console.

May it be a problem/bug in IPython, is it intended, or am I just not seeing something I did wrong? I have updated IPython but it changed nothing.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: have you tried `proc.terminate()` instead? It sends a TERMINATE signal, so maybe not what you want. But signals are kind of emulated on windows so maybe that's the best choice you have

Comment: Yes I have. Also win32api.GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent which doesn´t work either. I need it to stop cleanly sadly.